# ISupportIncrementalLoading в CollectionView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

UWP Windows 10.

Подскажите как реализовать виртуализацию для `ListView` с привязкой к `CollectionView` источником данных которого является группированный список `ObservableCollection`?

Сделал источник такого вида:

```
public class TransactionRepository : ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>, ISupportIncrementalLoading...
```

Реализовал все по примерам, данные вообще не отображаются. Возможно такой подход просто не применим для `CollectionView`?

Какие есть варианты?

Comment: А пример вам удалось скомпилировать, и работает верно?

Comment: @VladD Да работает с ListView напрямую

Comment: https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2014/08/14/incremental-load-grouped - говорят, не работает с группировкой.

Comment: Я так и понял. А какие есть варианты для группировки?

Comment: `ICollectionView`, по идее?